# URL for IBM Cloud Kubernetes deployment

Tags: python, flask, kubernetes, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-kubernetes

This is a bit of a beginner's question. I'm attempting to get a simple Hello World Python flask application deployed in a kubernetes cluster on IBM Cloud. The application (`main.py`):

```
import os
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def welcomeToMyapp():
    return 'Ciao'

port = os.getenv('PORT', '5000')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=int(port))
```

I  build my Docker image with `docker build --rm -t kube-hw .` and `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

WORKDIR /app
ADD requirements.txt /app
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

ADD main.py /app

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["python3", "main.py"]
```

I run it locally with `docker run --rm -p 5000:5000 kube-hw`. That works fine. I can browse `http://0.0.0.0:5000/`.

However, when I run the same image on k8s on IBM Cloud I can't seem to access the URL endpoint. My deployment steps are (from the article mentioned in the answer below):

```
docker tag kube-hw registry.ng.bluemix.net/sudoku/kube-hw:latest
docker push registry.ng.bluemix.net/sudoku/kube-hw:latest
kubectl run kube-hw --image=registry.ng.bluemix.net/sudoku/kube-hw:latest --port=80
kubectl expose deployment kube-hw --port=80 --target-port=5000 --type=NodePort
```

I then use `kubectl describe pod kube-hw` to get the external IP address `10.77.223.141`:

```
Name:           kube-hw-3409617459-5bczp
Namespace:      default
Node:           10.77.223.141/10.77.223.141
Start Time:     Sat, 23 Dec 2017 14:52:39 -0500

Status:         Running
IP:             172.30.205.113
```

And `kubectl describe service kube-hw` to get the port `30930`:

```
Name:                     kube-hw
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   run=kube-hw
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 run=kube-hw
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       172.21.250.32
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               5000/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30930/TCP
Endpoints:                172.30.205.116:5000
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

The URL `http:\\10.77.223.141:30930` doesn't resolve. I can look at the log and see the app running, but no requests are getting to it. The article uses `--target-port=8888`. But since I've used port `5000` in the container I changed to `--target-port=5000`. I'm wondering if I have a misalignment of port numbers somewhere.

Comment: 10.x.x.x is not an external address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP address that you need is the external IP address of a worker node in your cluster. The IP address that you have identified is an internal address.

To get an external IP address, run `bx cs workers <cluster_name>`

Then form the URL as follows: `http://<external_node_ip>:<NodePort>`

Here's a doc with more information on using NodePort: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_apps.html#cs_apps_public_nodeport

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Use `bx cs workers <cluster name>` to get the public IP. and `kubectl describe service <service name>` to get the IP. I may actually have tried that earlier. The other thing I realized was that despite this being a hello world app, I'm building a big image and it was taking time to load. I may not have been waiting long enough.

Answer (score 0):

The command changed, now it is

`ibmcloud cs workers --cluster your_cluster_name`